# jQuery Isotope: Hiding items initially

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope, jquery-masonry

So I have items that can have multiple classes for filtering. Something like this:

```
<div class="items>
    <div class="item category-1 category-2">An item that displays initially.</div>
    <div class="item category-1 category-2 initially-hidden">An item that is initially hidden.</div>
    <div class="item category-1 category-2">An item that displays initially.</div>
    <div class="item category-1 category-2 initially-hidden">An item that is initially hidden.</div>
    <div class="item category-1 category-2">An item that displays initially.</div>
</div>
```

With isotope, how can I hide items with a certain class on page load? Say I want to hide any item with a class of `initially-hidden` on load, but still be able to have that item show up when I click a filter for any other class that item has? For the example code above, say I clicked a `category-2` filter, then then all items that have `category-2` (even if they have `initially-hidden`) would appear?

Basically on a project I'm working on, a client wants to be able to initially hide items on page load, but then show them when filtering. So I have created a way for her to tag those with `initially-hidden`, but can't wrap my head around how to hide those initially, but then still allow them to show up when an associated filter is clicked.

I've come across [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/desandro/KWvME/) by desandro, but it's not exactly what I'm looking for because it assumes each item only has 1 class (red, green, OR blue).

**EDIT**

Here's a fork of desandro's fiddle that I edited to be more like my situation (items can have multiple classes). [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tenold/d7n10sq8/1/).

**FINAL EDIT**

The answer seems to be to do the opposite, add an `initially-shown` class and filter those on page load. So instead of having my client tag everything as `initially-shown`, I went with this method:

```
$container.find('.tile:not(.initially-hidden)').addClass('initially-shown');
```

Because they have 100s of items, and only seem to hide a handful.

Here's an updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tenold/d7n10sq8/3/).

Comment: any reason you can't just use `style="display:none;"`, or set the css of `.initially-hidden` to have `display:none`?

Comment: Show us the code you have already - this is likely a solution for CSS.

Comment: That would be more or less http://jsfiddle.net/KWvME/93/

Comment: @DLeh, it's not that easy, that's the first thing I tried.

Comment: @neiesc, ha, see my edit to the original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I mean there are a couple of ways to achieve this result: On dom ready create a filter that only shows the results you want, then trigger isotope.

```
<div class="items>
    <div class="item category-1 categor-2 initial-show">An item that displays initially.</div>
    <div class="item category-1 category-2 initially-hidden">An item that is initially hidden.</div>
    <div class="item category-1 category-2 initial-show">An item that displays initially.</div>
    <div class="item category-1 category-2 initially-hidden">An item that is initially hidden.</div>
    <div class="item category-1 category-2 initial-show">An item that displays initially.</div>
</div>
```

### JS

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var PageLoadFilter = '.initial-show';
  $container.isotope({ filter: PageLoadFilter});
});
```

Your fiddle set to filter red by default:
http://jsfiddle.net/KWvME/96/

Comment: But I want all filters to show, with the exception of initially-hidden. That's what I don't know how to do. Since category-2 can also have a class of initially-hidden or not, that's what makes this trickier.

Comment: add class initial-show on items you want to show and filter by that?

Comment: This works, but instead of my client having to tag everything as initially-shown, I did this instead: `$container.find('.item:not(.initially-hidden)').addClass('initially-shown');` before calling isotope.

Answer (score 1):

To best work with Isotope, do the reverse -

instead of `.initially-hidden` do `.initially-shown` and have the filter default to that.

`$container.isotope({ filter: '.initially-shown'});`

or perhaps you can do a selector like this:

`$container.isotope({ filter: ':not(.initially-shown)'});`

but I doubt that would work...

Answer (score 0):

When I am trying this, the items that are not loaded on the initial load (initially-shown), do not show when you click other views.